# "ibtool not found. Please ensure the Apple SDK is installed."

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, monodevelop, monomac

since I updated my Xcode to 3.2.5 I get an error when I try to build a MonoMac project I'm working on.

```
"ibtool not found. Please ensure the Apple SDK is installed."
```

Did anyone of you guys ever have that before? Is there a way to manually reconfigure the path to Interface Builder in MonoDevelop? MonoDevelop is version 2.4.

Thanks
–f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure how to solve the problem but re-installing Xcode 3.2.4 did the trick for me.

Best
–f

Comment: I un-installed Xcode and installed the older version I had somewhere on my hard disk.